# Go over directories in Uipath

Tags: search, directory, uipath

I want to go over a directory and delete all files older than x, in Uipath. My problem is that I don't know how to go over another folder that may be inside.

[image: Here is what I have.]

[image: And here]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far. Please try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: I just edit the post and posted some photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to enumerate over each file in a folder and all potential subfolders: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

You may then use `File.GetAttributes(file)` to return a `FileAttributes` object which will expose detailed information about the file"s creation date, for example (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

[image: iterating over files including sub directories]

Answer (score 0):

**Use UiPath.Core.Activities.InvokePowerShell**

Commandtext (Sample):

```
("Remove-Item -Path "  + Path.Combine([YOURPATH], "*.*") + " -Force -Recurse")
```

This removes all files in the directory recursive.